# Fancybox closes on re-render of output panel

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, rerender

I have an apex datatable structured something like this:

```
<apex:datatable id="pbtblObj" value="{!lstvalues}" var="varObj">
<apex:column headervalue="Action">
    <div class="alignCenter">
        <apex:commandlink styleclass="addpopup" action="{!varObj.enableEditMode}" html-popup-id="{!varObj.objObjectives.Id}Edit"  status="Processing" rerender="editPopRndr" oncomplete="showpopup(this , 'testing');">Edit</apex:commandlink>
    </div>

    <!-- Edit pop-up-->
    <div id="{!varObj.objObjectives.Id}Edit" class="display_none_ele">
        <apex:outputPanel id="editPopRndr" >
            <apex:outputpanel rendered="{!varObj.bolEditMode}">
                <div class="popUpBody alignCenter">
                    <table align="center" style="valign:top;">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="alignRight" valign="top">Definition:</td>
                            <td class="alignLeft"><apex:inputfield value="{!varObj.obj.Description__c}"/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>

            </apex:outputpanel>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </div>                            
</apex:column>
```

Here is the flow of execution:

1. The table contains a column containing a commanbutton ("Edit"), on click of the command button "Edit", a method is called which sets a boolean to true and rerenders the output panel "editPopRndr".
2. This output panel is within a div "{someId}Edit" which is hidden by default, and contains an some output fields.
3. Onclick of the commandbutton ("Edit"), #1 is triggered, and oncomplete a javascript is called which should display the div "{someId}Edit", which now has its inner contents rendered in a pop-up.
4. I am using fancybox

Comment: Not sure how this is marked as off topic since this problem is peculiar to Salesforces re-rendering and someone using pure HTML/CSS or anyother JS MVC platform is not going hit this one.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out what was going wrong,

**The exact issue causing the pop-up to not appear/persist:**

All the re-renders were calling an actionstatus, which onstop was re-initializing the jquery (fancybox) for the entire page. Since onstop event of an actionstatus is triggred after the oncomplete event on the commanbutton the pop-up was being called but would disappear when the onstop re-initialized the jquery.

**The solution:**

1. Create another action status which does not initializes any jquery, basically no onstop event
2. Use this new (no onstop event) actionstatus in the commandbutton in the status property
3. Add the required jquery in the oncomplete event of the commandbutton

Everything works like a charm.

**Please add in your thought and comments on the solution, also would be gladly interested in knowing what other ways could this be solved.**

Thanks, and hope this helps someone in future!